# Cant configure LAMP on kali linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, sockets

Hello guys is me again now I have some problems configuring LAMP

first of all i have install everything but  I cant run test.php to see if php works according to `ifconfig` command my addr is: **192.168.1.77** So in browser when I try to run `192.168.1.77/test.php` nothing happens.I follow the instructions in this video to do that. [How to set up a Debian LAMP Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lfs0jExxVGE)

Second when I try to change the password on mysql I got this error by the way I can't do anything that has to do with mysql. when I run this command `apache2 -v && mysql -v && php -v`
 I got this error.

> Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server built:   Feb  1 2014
>   21:26:04 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

when I try to run this command `/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'mypassword'` i got this error.

> /usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error:
>   'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and
>   that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

I follow this guide to [LAMP, Linux Apache MySQL PHP](https://wiki.debian.org/LaMp) But since I have those problems with mysql i can't finish the proper configuration. so thank you very much for any help or comments have and have a nice day.

Comment: Your sql server is not running, I don't know how kali linux works exactly but try `service mysql start` OR `/etc/init.d/mysql`. Something inside me tells me your apache server is also not running, same commands, `service apache2 start` OR `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`, then try to access your ip again, also, try localhost instead to see if maybe it's a firewall thing or whatever.

Comment: It's Works like a charm thank you very much. I'm going to continue the configuration of the Tiers. I hope everything will be all right, if anything goes wrong i will tell you.

Comment: well I continue the configuration test.php works fine but I got this error know when I trying to set another password with this command: **/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'enter-your-good-new-password-here'**  <br/> I gotthis is the error: **/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'**

Comment: First off you can't see jack from the link you provided. Try it like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lfs0jExxVGE

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search might be able to point you the right direction, did you install this?

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

It seems to be complaining about mysqld which is the mysql-server program perhaps try this too:

service mysql start

You will see this:

```
[ ok ] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld ..
[info] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly..
```

Notice how it says mysqld

If that doesn't work try this maybe:

```
apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

Hopefully this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

Kali blacklists services by default using sysvinit, so if you've been rebooting it could be tripping you up:

http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-network-service-policies

Comment: This link may present an answer, but links can and do change which would make this answer irrelevant.  Please place any relevant code or documentation here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just also going to throw out there that it seems like there are some issues with installing mysql now so instead you're better off installing mariadb. so instead of

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

try

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
```